# VB.net MYSQL connector max_allowed_packet error

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have developed a VB.net app that connects to a MySQL database. Randomly I am getting an error related to max_allowed_packet size (Packets larger than "max_allowed_packet" are not allowed) for select statements. The MySQL is running on a dedicated Linux server and the max_allowed_packet is set to 256MB. BTW, the same query runs on MySQL workbench and runs on the same VB app without any problems but the error happens sometimes without being able to track why. Is there anything I should look at or is it related to the MySQL .net connector?

Comment: can you try to run the same query on "mysql" command line once, and check what you got.

Comment: It's telling you that the issue occurs when executing a `SELECT` statement. That is **LOADS** of information.  It means that you know that you can add an exception handler in every location that you are executing a `SELECT` statement and then log the exception and any other information that might be useful, like what the query was. You might not even need to do it for every query because, if you were always doing the same thing when it happened, you already know where in the code it is occurring.

Comment: @jmcilhinney It happens with several queries and it doesn't happen when I run the query directly through MySQL Workbench. When I update the max_allowed_packet and restart MySQL, it works again.

Comment: @Vivek The problem is that it only happens rarely and I am not able to check how it's happening.

Comment: If it might happen on any query then add exception handling and logging to every query.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I did it doesn't help to know the source of the problem and why it's happening